# Sharpness of matrix Bernstein inequality

Tags: random-matrices, coupon-collector

I'm self-studying Vershynin's High-Dimensional Probability.
The aim of exercise 5.4.14 is to provide a sharpness result related to the matrix Bernstein inequality.
It reads:

> Let $X$ be an $n\times n$ random matrix that takes values $e_ke_k^T$, $k=1,\dots,n$, with probability $1/n$ each. ($e_k$ is the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$).
> Let $X_1,\dots,X_N$ be independent copies of $X$.
> Consider the sum $S=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$, which is a diagonal matrix.
> (b) Relating this to the classical coupon collector's problem, show that if $N\asymp n$, then $$E||S||\asymp \frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$$

Here's what I tried:
Part (a) asked to show that $S_{ii}$ is the number of balls in the $i$-th bin, when $N$ balls are thrown into $n$ bins independently, which is:
$$P[S_{ii}=k]={{N}\choose{k}}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{N-k}$$
Since $N\asymp n$, I tried to work with the binomial distribution (with parameters $N\asymp n$ and $1/n$).
If so, $ES_{ii}=N/n\asymp 1$.
Since $S$ is a diagonal matrix, $||S||=\max_{1\leq i \leq  n}S_{ii}$, so we have a maximum over dependent binomials.
By these elementary techniques, I get the crude bound:
$$E||S||\leq \sum_{i=1}^nES_{ii}\asymp n$$
Can you help me to prove the stronger bound given in the exercise, and to understand the connection to the coupon collector's problem?